# last date of the month not being displayed in DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I am using `DatePickerDialog` to select the date. When the month start from last day of the week, and has 31 days, it doesn't display last day of that month. For example December 2019 starts on Sunday, date 30th and 31st are not being displayed.

I tried to set `datepickerdialog.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calender.SUNDAY)`. This issue will be still remain the same for the months which starts from Saturday.

```
dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    JobAssignedActivity.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            );


            Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
 dpd.setMinDate(minDate);
            dpd.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
            dpd.setAccentColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.mdtp_accent_color));
            dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
```

How to display last row for the month?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will give proper output

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
        Log.v("onDateSet",dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year);
    }

};

final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
new DatePickerDialog(YourActivity.this, onDateSetListener, 
    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankit, but I get same output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first declare DatePickerDialog

```
Calendar Calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpdialog = new DatePickerDialog(JobAssignedActivity.this, date, Calendar1
   .get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
   Calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dpdialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
dpdialog.show(); //put this whenever you want show the dialog
```

and add the date listener method outside oncreate.

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            Calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            Calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateCalendar1(); //whatever function/method you need after selecting a date
        }

    };
```

Your operation.

```
private void updateCalendar1() {
        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        etdate.setText(sdf.format(Calendar1.getTime()));
    }
```

Comment: in this code you can change `dpdialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());` to `dpdialog.getDatePicker();` only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this `com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker` design date picker if you set version of date picker `dpd.setVersion(DatePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_1);`